# Gradle task execution time: compileKotlin is way slower than compileJava?

Tags: performance, kotlin, gradle

We have a multi-module Gradle project, and some of our modules have Kotlin and Java code.
The `compileKotlin` tasks take way longer than the `compile java tasks even though most of our codebase is still Java code - is there a known performance loss to mixing Java and Kotlin source in one module?

| module | compile task | LOC | execution time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| teamecho-global | kotlin | 155 | 10s |
|  | java | 1.103 | 2s |
| teamecho-base | kotlin | 3899 | 16s |
|  | java | 41.414 | 9s |
| teamecho-satisfaction | kotlin | 3.600 | 10s |
|  | java | 6.183 | 3s |
| teamecho-dynamic-frontend | kotlin | 337 | 3s |

Gradle Build Scan:

https://scans.gradle.com/s/o4avvpmrrg3oi/timeline

What surprises me the most is the 10 seconds spend on compiling the 155 LOC in the global module.
In comparison to that the dynamic-frontend module only takes about 3 seconds for 330 LOC (which is still a lot!?) but is still way faster than the 155 lines from the global module. Could this be because the dynamic-frontend module has no java code?

We would like to implement more and more of our code base in Kotlin but if the Gradle build time gets so much worse, I am not sure if we should continue with it. Any tips or pin points to what we can do to decrease the time the `compileKotlin` task takes? We must be doing something wrong or is this performance expected?